# How to bind properties between two classes with Combine?

Tags: swift, combine

How to make a mechanism similar to binding in the view that refers to the Published in the ObservableObject class, but between 2 classes? That is, from class A, call the class B constructor, passing the prop1 from class A. And in class B prop2 exists, and these prop1 and prop2 should mirror each other.

PS: Attached code does not work, just visually show what I want ...

PPS: prop1 in ClassA and prop2 in ClassB, must be Published by condition. It's own views are also subscribed on it.

PPPS: Important to have any binding logic inside the ClassB, for easy reuse.

```
class ClassA: ObservableObject {
    @Published var prop1: Bool = false //When prop1 changed, it must be reflected in prop2
    let classB: ClassB

    init() {
        classB = .init(prop2: _prop1) //Should stay that simple, no setup here, passing only property, ClassB doesn't know about ClassA.
    }
}

class ClassB: ObservableObject {
    @Published var prop2: Bool //When prop2 changed, it must be reflected in prop1

    init(prop2: Published<Bool>) {
        _prop2 = prop2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple but generic solution could look like the following.

Add the following extension:

```swift
extension Published.Publisher where Value: Equatable {
    mutating func link(with other: inout Self) {
        removeDuplicates().assign(to: &other)
        other.removeDuplicates().assign(to: &self)
    }
}
```

This only works with values that conform to `Equatable`, because otherwise you might end up in an endless loop.

Then call the extension in the initializer of `ClassA`:

```swift
classB.$prop2.link(with: &$prop1)
```

---

**Original Answer(s)**

A simple solution would be to put the following code into your `init` of `ClassA`:

```swift
$prop1
    .removeDuplicates()
    .assign(to: &classB.$prop2) // mirror changes of prop1 into classB.prop2
classB.$prop2
    .removeDuplicates()
    .assign(to: &$prop1) // mirror changes of classB.prop2 into prop1
```

However, I'd recommend removing `prop1` from `ClassA` and accessing this value via `classB.prop2` and `classB.$prop2`, respectively. This makes the dependency clearer and doesn't require storing and updating the value in two places.

---

**Answer to question in comments regarding putting the logic in ClassB**

To do this, you could add a function in `ClassB` that performs the linking:

```swift
fileprivate func linkProps(to classA: ClassA) {
    $prop2
        .removeDuplicates()
        .assign(to: &classA.$prop1) // mirror changes of prop2 into classA.prop1
    classA.$prop1
        .removeDuplicates()
        .assign(to: &$prop2) // mirror changes of classA.prop1 into prop2
}
```

And then call this function in the `init` of `ClassA` (and wherever else you need to):

```swift
init() {
    classB = .init(prop2: _prop1)
    classB.linkProps(to: self)
}
```

---

**Answer to question in comments regarding keeping ClassB from knowing ClassA**

This could be achieved by only passing the property wrapper's projected value into the function on `ClassB`:

```swift
fileprivate func linkProp2(to prop1: inout Published<Bool>.Publisher) {
    $prop2
        .removeDuplicates()
        .assign(to: &prop1) // mirror changes of prop2 into prop1
    prop1
        .removeDuplicates()
        .assign(to: &$prop2) // mirror changes of prop1 into prop2
}
```

The call in the initializer of `ClassA` would then look like this:

```swift
classB.linkProp2(to: &$prop1)
```

Comment: Thanks Florian! It's important to have that binding code inside the ClassB, so it's easily reusable. Can it be achieved?

Comment: Accessing it via classB.$prop2 is not the solution unfortunately because View has ObservedObject property only of ClassA type.

Comment: @bodich I've just updated my answer to reflect your question here.

Comment: @bodich But if you have `ClassA` inside your View, then you also have access to the value in `ClassB`: `@ObservedObject var classA; let prop = classA.classB.prop2;`

Comment: Thank! Answering the questions.
1. Yes, I have access to classA.classB.prop2 but don't have reactive behaviour. I only have to make @ObservedObject var classB as well to make view updated on prop2 changes.
2. Does it any way to avoid ClassB knowledge about ClassA? I mean by passing only property, like we do with View. We pass property only and it's able to make Binding to it.

Comment: Instead of references to the classes, pass references to the publishers: AnyPublisher<Bool>

Comment: @bodich I've updated the question again with an answer to your second question... Regarding your first question, you are right. But in general it sounds like you should think about re-modeling your data structure and putting these values into one shared model instead of storing them in multiple classes. Or use `Binding` to share values stored in another location. But whether that's possible and how it would look like is hard to tell without more insight into the code - which you probably can't provide. :)

Comment: Thanks @FlorianFriedrich. Overall the last solution is what I was looking for.

Can you please tell me more detailed what you meant with using Binding? It's about Views or you mean something else? If you have some more time...

Comment: @bodich If you have `ClassA` as `@ObservedObject` in your view somewhere, you can use `$classA.classB` or `$classA.prop1` to get a binding to these values and pass these around to the next view. The view should still update if the value of the binding changes, but the storage of the value stays within `ClassA`.